# Shortcut key to toggle "Enable On Screen Display (OSD)" in VLC

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vlc-media-player

Right now in VLC, I can go to "Preferences" > "Subtitles / OSD", check or uncheck "Enable On Screen Display (OSD)", then click "Save":

[image]

Is there a shortcut key for me to achieve the above? (And if there isn't already one, is there a way for me to assign one?)

Comment: Short answer: No, see [45 Shortcuts for VLC Media Player (Windows)](https://shortcutworld.com/VLC-Media-Player/win/VLC-Media-Player_Shortcuts). Long answer: You could program one with [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)

Comment: Thanks. I do use AHK. What is the code I'd put for AHK?

Comment: That's for you to figure out ... whatever keystrokes are required to get to that screen and toggle the option ...